# Can't apply 3d properties to autoshape

Tags: vba, excel

The workbook I am working on in Excel uses graphics with 3d properties which are set in VBA.  I just changed an image in the workbook, and now Excel complains that it can't execute any of the following lines of code:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.ThreeD.Depth = fsdoord
Selection.ShapeRange.ThreeD.ExtrusionColor.RGB = carcol
Selection.ShapeRange.ThreeD.PresetLightingDirection = msoLightingBottom
```

The error produced is

```
Run-time error '70':

Permission denied
```

I can still apply all the other properties to this shape; it only errors when I try to execute the lines relating to the 3d properties.

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I sort of found the problem.  When I replaced the image, I deleted the original image and inserted a new one using Insert>Image>From File... It turns out that the original image must have had some sort of 3d properties applied already, because when I replaced the image by just changing the fill colour of the auto-shape, it worked (in other words, I kept all the properties and only changed the fill).

Answer (score 0):

ShapeRange is actually a collection of Shapes. You need to drill down one more level to get the shape object. (As the properties you are trying to use apply to Excel.Shape.)

```
    Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim shp As Excel.Shape
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set shp = ws.Shapes(1)
    shp.ThreeD.Depth = 10.5!
    shp.ThreeD.ExtrusionColor.RGB = &HF08300
    shp.ThreeD.PresetLightingDirection = msoLightingBottom
End Sub
Sub Example2()
    Dim shpRng As Excel.ShapeRange
    Dim shp As Excel.Shape
    Set shpRng = Selection.ShapeRange
    Set shp = shpRng.Item(1)
    shp.ThreeD.Depth = 25.5!
    shp.ThreeD.ExtrusionColor.RGB = &HFF0083
    shp.ThreeD.PresetLightingDirection = msoLightingBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using the exact code I pasted above, or are you trying to get the shape by name? Because trying to create a shape with a name that already exists will throw that specific error as well.

Comment: I used my code but tried referencing the object as ...ShapeRange.Item(1)... - it still had the same error

Comment: Then I'd have to say the problem lies outside of the code block you posted. Can you go ahead and post the whole procedure?

Answer (score 0):

There's a remark on the Help page for the `ThreeDFormat` object and it's repeated on the MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210289.aspx)

> You cannot apply three-dimensional
>   formatting to some kinds of shapes,
>   such as beveled shapes or
>   multiple-disjoint paths. Most of the
>   properties and methods of the
>   ThreeDFormat object for such a shape
>   will fail.

So if your new shape falls into one of those rather sketchily-defined categories then that might be your problem

Comment: No, neither of these categories - its an image, and before I changed the image it worked fine (I only replaced the image with a different picture)